# Javascript GPS math

Tags: javascript, gps, physics

I need a javascript function that updates current position based on speed, heading, and time elapsed.

`function getUpdatedPosition(oldLat, oldLon, speedInMetersPerSec, headingInDegrees, durationInSeconds)`

Where "headingInDegrees"  is Direction of travel, specified in degrees counting clockwise relative to the true north. (Number)

Which would return a geoPosition object like this: 
{lat: 43.34532, lon: -84.23421}  accurate and precise to 5 decimal places.

With regards to accuracy, I am calculating over short distances with frequent updates and therefore a linear approximation is sufficient.

Comment: I think it is something like (sin(toRadians(headingInDegrees))*speedInMetersPerSec*durationInSeconds) is the Latitude and (sin(toRadians(headingInDegrees))*speedInMetersPerSec*durationInSeconds) is the Longitude. I'm not sure, tho. ou might have to add some offsets to headingInDegrees depending on the system you are doing this on(on some systems 0 degrees is right, on others it is left etc.)

Comment: also, I think the physics tag shouldn't be there

Comment: Thanks iani...  Really wish you could have formatted your answer in an actual post though...  Based on the description of "headingInDegrees" i'd say it is safe to assume 0 degrees is true north.  No?

Answer (score 0):

See "Problem 1c" in http://www.codeguru.com/Cpp/Cpp/algorithms/article.php/c5115.

"distance" would be `speedInMetersPerSec * durationInSeconds` for you, obviously.